# Create new page in angularjs blur-admin

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

According to [the tutorial](https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/013-create-new-page/) I've added new page and module, but [it doesn't seem to work](https://github.com/majkelo/blur-admin/tree/blur-admin-tutorial) (neither it's shown in a sidebar, nor I can get it via direct url). What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the 
**newPage** that you have added has module name as **BlurAdmin.pages.myNewPage**
and state as **myNewPage** as given in the code

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.myNewPage', [])
    .config(routeConfig);
    /** @ngInject */
    function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('myNewPage', {
            url: '/myNewPage',
            templateUrl: 'app/pages/myNewPage/my-new-page.html',
            title: 'My New Page',
            sidebarMeta: {
                order: 800,
            },
        });
    }

})();
```

Now goto *src/app/pages* you will find **pages.module.js**. You should add mentioned new module to list:

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages', [
    'ui.router',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.ui',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.components',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.form',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.tables',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.charts',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.maps',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.profile',
    'BlurAdmin.pages.myNewPage'
])
```

And you are done.

Comment: its not working.
I get following error

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module BlurAdmin due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module BlurAdmin.pages due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module BlurAdmin.pages.myNewPage due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'BlurAdmin.pages.myNewPage' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

after adding the module name to pages.module.js re run gulp serve:dist